# Replace character (") with (\")

Tags: java, string

I need to replace character (") with (\") in Java
Such as: `Hello "Anne"!` to be changed to `Hello \"Anne\"!`

Any advice please?

```
value.replace("\"", ...?);
```

Comment: Well, what did you try for "..."? Did it work? If not, why not? (These silly question do have a point; the question - or trial deviations of it - already contains all the required information.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` the same way you escaped the `"`, so:

```
value.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
value.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

try with

```
value=value.replace("\"","\\\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use triple backslash:

```
value.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
value = value.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.replaceAll("\"","\\\"")` will work.

```
   String strNew=str.replaceAll("\"","\\\"");
```